# OpenShift Container Platform unable to pull private Docker Hub images

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift, docker-registry

I have an instance of OpenShift Container Platform 3.9 running.

1. I created a docker hub secrets with credentials to access private images.
2. I linked the newly created secret to the `default` service account for pull access.
3. I created an `ImageStream`, to access the private image, which seems to have access as it is correctly accessing the image sha.
4. I created a `DeploymentConfig` to deploy the image. When deploying, I get the following error message when attempting to pull the image `Failed to pull image "myorg/myimage": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = repository docker.io/myorg/myimage not found: does not exist or no pull access`

The image stream looks as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ImageStream
metadata:
  name: myimage
spec:
  dockerImageRepository: docker.io/myorg/myimage
  tags:
    - name: mytag
      generation: 2
      from:
        kind: DockerImage
        name: 'docker.io/myorg/myimage:mytag'
      importPolicy:
        scheduled: true
```

The deployment config looks as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: DeploymentConfig
metadata:
  name: myservice
  generation: 1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: example
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myservice
        image: myorg/myimage:mytag
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8888
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever figure out the issue Patrick?  I've run into the same problem

Comment: @JGlass it was an issue with the platform. I'm not sure if they corrected it:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1601206
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1600539

Comment: Thanks for replying!  I'm actually working with a Red Hat employee and support to figure out the issue as it's still occurring - If we get it figured out I'll add it as an answer if its worthy!  Have a great one!